# MKMapView contraints in storyboard issue

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, uistoryboard

I have this constaints for map view

[image]

[image]

But I have this error

[image]

If I replace map view with UIView, everything is OK

**Update**

To reproduce you need to set settings of view controller like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK got it solved at my end. Change the MKMapView's frame **x:0 y:0 Width:375 Height:554** and than see is it still there or not.

[See the setting. It is as same as you have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDm2n.png)

[Update the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnTij.png)

**Note:** Sorry Don't know How to add images in answer.

Answer (score 0):

i will tray it look like good and not showing error .........

Tray to add constraint like equal width to view and equal height to view.....

i think any of other constraint are creating a error first check all the constraint of your view.....

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "equal width, equal height" constraint along with "Horizontally in Container" & "Vertically in Container"

Or

You click on the "red dot" and click on add missing constraint. See which constraint it adds after that It will help to understand the issue.

Comment: pls take a look at my Update

Comment: I post new answer. Did it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue when I tried to put an MKMapView as a full screen view. To do so I set:

- Center horizontally
- Center vertically
- Equal widths
- Equal heights

These above are referred to the MKMapView's superview (the main controller view). And xCode kept saying me "Error: missing constraints for Y position". I had never seen this error doing the way I did. I solved with these other four constraints (equivalent in my opinion):

- Leading space 0
- Trailing space 0
- Top space 0
- Bottom space 0

Always referred to the MKMapView's superview (the main controller view).